# How do I parse an XML file in Java using either DOM or JAXB when file only has attributes

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb

I apologize in advance for my ignorance but am desperate for help. 
I am writing a java program that needs to read the following XML file snippets with either DOM or JAXB and will group all attributes in each

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<obj id="A" text="helpme1" name="button1">                
   <text text="save1" priority="yellow"/>
   <app node="first" desc="newnode1"/>
</obj>
<obj id="B" text="helpme2" name="button2">                
   <text text="save2" priority="red"/>
   <app node="second" desc="newnode2"/>
</obj>
```

Ultimate need:To be able to create an object for helpme1 and helpme2
that contains objects called text and app that go with each `<obj`. How does one parse this XML to get the `<obj` with `text="helpme1"` and the `<text` and `<app` below it and then get the `<obj` with `text="helpme2` and the `<text` and `<app`
below that? Ultimately as I loop throw this file, I will have a map 
that will set helpme1 and helpme2 as keys and the values will
be objects that will consist of `<text` and `<app` that are associated
with each `<obj` in the file. I am familiar with both JAXB and DOM.  Those are my 2 options.  I do not have a Schema.
Any suggestion are appreciated and I am well aware that I am ignorant
so please go easy. Thank you.

Comment: This is not well formed XML.

Comment: Perhaps you should start by having a read through [Java API for XML Processing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/)

Comment: This is the only XML I have to work with. This is just a snippet.

Comment: It should look like this:
<obj id="A" text="helpme1" name="button1">  
     <text text="save1" priority="yellow"/>
     <app node="first" desc="newnode1"/>
</obj>

Comment: @elaine808 - If this is what you have to work with, then you are (to be blunt) screwed.  No legitimate XML parser will parse that.  Please check that what you have shown us is an >>accurate<< reflection of what you need to process.

Comment: @Stephen C Thank you for your reply! I should have been more careful. I edited the question with the correct format.

Comment: It is still not well-formed XML, because it has more than one top-level element. See [Well-formedness](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/xml/882/getting-started-with-xml/3210/well-formedness) for explanation.